# C# how to determine, whether ArrayList contains object with certain attribute

Tags: c#, arraylist, contains

I have an ArrayList of objects of my custom class. I would like to know, if ArrayList contains object with certain attribute. I do not care about the object, just if there is some. Yes, I could do this with foreach cycle, but I was wondering if there was more elegant way to do so.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, to start with I'd suggest using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`. Then LINQ to Objects makes it really easy:

```
if (list.Any(x => x.HasFoo))
{
}
```

Or without LINQ (but still `List<T>`)

```
if (list.FindIndex(x => x.HasFoo) != -1)
{
}
```

If you *really* need to stick with a non-generic collection but have LINQ to Objects available too, you can use:

```
if (arrayList.Cast<YourType>().Any(x => x.HasFoo))
{
}
```

Comment: Why do people so often confuse extension methods with LINQ? LINQ as per the name is a language integrated query of the form: from x in collection where condition select... which can be translated to a method chain like collection.Where(x=>condition).Select(x=>stuff)

Comment: @edvaldig: It's more than that - it's a whole collection of technologies. This is using LINQ to Objects, for example. I'll happily update the answer to clarify that, but I think it's still reasonable to say this code is "using LINQ".

Comment: Thank you. First variant is exactly what I wanted! I also replaced ArrayList with List<T> so that I have all functionality I need.

Answer (score -1):

use Linq:

```
var query = from o in yourarray select o where o.atribute==ValueIWant;


`query.Count()` will return the number of objects that fit the condition.
```

check that msdn example: [Linq example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: That won't compile (select before where), would be inelegant if it did (the query expression is more verbose than just a single `Where` call), and would be inefficient (using `Count()` instead of `Any()` requires testing against the whole collection, instead of stopping when it finds the first match. Oh, and you'd need `Cast<>` or an explicitly typed range variable to work with `ArrayList` in the first place...