# Checking if ArrayList<> cointains a object dont work

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My app downloading a Events from sqldatabase and add it to ArrayList<>. It do aduplicate so I wrote:

```
public static ArrayList<Events> list = new ArrayList<Events>();

  static void addevhlp(Events e){

        if (list.contains(e)){
         Log.d("","it cointains")
        }
        else {
            list.add(e);
        }

    }
```

But it never say me the list cointans element. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: would you please provide more code.

Answer (score 3):

you have to `override` `equals` in `Events`, and define when two events are equals. The default implementation checks for equal object's reference. For instance, if your Events class has an `int id` field

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Events)) {
         return false;
    }
    Events event = (Events) o;
    return id == event.id;
}
```

Comment: Id in my app is String and i want just compare the new e.id to existing events in arraylist

Comment: if it is a string use equals. `return id.equals(event.id)`

Answer (score 0):

You should overrides `equals` and `hashCode` in your Events object.
See : 
[Best implementation for hashCode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation) for detail about hashCode

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) about `ArrayList.contains`:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

So, `contains` uses the equals implementation of your `Events` class to check if it holds the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (list.contains(e))
```

If the events e has the same Reference than the one you have in the ArrayList the contains will work. 
but If you want to check if the value is the same, but with a different Reference, you have to check if the properties of your events are exists or equals.

or you can simply use LINQ with List instead of ArrayList
[C# how to determine, whether ArrayList contains object with certain attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292452/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-arraylist-contains-object-with-certain-attribu)